# Thinglink image not visible until browser resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I am trying to repurpose a pre-existing theme, which includes a drop down menu that displays an image. I am trying to embed a Thinglink into the drop down menu's content section, but it is not visible until I resize the browser window.

Here is what the menu looks like:
[image: asdf]

Then when clicked, I can see an empty space where the image should show:
[image: asdf]

Then when browser is resized, the image appears:
[image: asdf]

This is the code for the content of the menu:

```
<div class="ajax_accordion_content" style="display: none;">
  <div class="report-detail">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="table_basic">
      <tbody>
      <!-- ThingLink image to be embedded -->
        <img style="max-width: 100%;" src="http://cdn.thinglink.me/api/image/832705713204625409/1024/10/scaletowidth#tl-832705713204625409;1043138249'" class="alwaysThinglink"/>
        <script async charset="utf-8" src="http://cdn.thinglink.me/jse/embed.js"></script>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I set the ajax_accordion_content display to block, then the image displays correctly. However, I want it to be hidden until I click on the menu. How can I get the image to load when the menu is opened without having to resize the browser?

Comment: Try img width 100% coz you already set table width 100 % ..

Comment: Create demo like js fiddle

Comment: @MostafaBaezid I did, but that has not fixed it.

Comment: @kreesh make a fiddle please

Answer (score 0):

look like you want a jQuery click function. I dnt know your menu section so I add a button for example .. Here is a live fiddle link
[https://jsfiddle.net/ve04q9sm/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/ve04q9sm/1/)

```js
$(function() {
  $("#display-img").click(function() {
   $(".ajax_accordion_content").toggle('slow')
   $(this).find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-menu-right glyphicon-menu-down');
   })

})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button id="display-img" class="btn btn-primary"><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></i></span>Kid who did not get rounded</button>
 <div class="ajax_accordion_content" style="display: none;">
  <div class="report-detail">
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="table_basic">
   <tbody>
<!-- ThingLink image to be embedded -->
<img style="max-width: 100%;" src="http://cdn.thinglink.me/api/image/832705713204625409/1024/10/scaletowidth#tl-832705713204625409;1043138249'" class="alwaysThinglink" />
<script async charset="utf-8" src="http://cdn.thinglink.me/jse/embed.js"></script>
  </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
</div>
```